# Is it possible to start chromium with a chrome:// url?

Tags: chromium

I would like to create a launcher launching:

```
chromium-browser chrome://inspect
```

However, this simply opens the chromium as if not url has been specified at all.

Is it even to start Chromium opening a `chrome://` url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While "normal" url's do work as expected, it seems impossible at first to use the `chrome://` urls from a command, and there is nothing in the `man chromium-browser` man page on this.

However, it is very well possible to work around this, with the help of [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/xdotool.1.html).

#### How it works

- install `xdotool`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Use the following command in your `.desktop` file:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "chromium-browser&sleep 2&&xdotool type 'chrome://inspect'&&xdotool key Return"
  ```

What it will do is open `chromium browser`, `xdotool` will type the `chrome://inspect` url and (simulate) press return.

*Effectively* this will do exactly what you want.
No need to say that you can replace `chrome://inspect` with any other of the `chrome://` commands.

#### Note

In the command, there is a small break included of 2 seconds, to make sure the browser is loaded before `xdotool` starts to type. On my system (not the most recent) it can be changed to `sleep 1` and still work perfectly. You can experiment a bit with it.

---

*edit*

#### Alternative

Dirty or not, a solution should *always* work. I tried the solution above now and then, and found that occasionally, it takes too long for the `chromium-browser` window to appear. Especially when the computer is heavily occupied, there is a chance xdotool starts typing "blindly".

The solution below is "time-proof" and should work under all circumstances; it makes sure `xdotool` *only* starts typing when a *new* `chromium-browser` window appears within appr. 15 seconds.

#### How to use

- Copy the script below into an empty file
- Save it as `run_chrcommand.py`
- use as command in your `.desktop` file:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/run_chrcommand.py
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import time

user = getpass.getuser()
get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", x]).decode("utf-8")
ws1 = get("wmctrl -lp"); t = 0
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "chromium-browser&"])
while t < 30:      
    ws2 = [w.split()[2] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if not w in ws1]
    procs = [[p for p in get("ps -u "+user).splitlines() \
              if "chromium-bro" in p and w in p] for w in ws2]
    if len(procs) > 0:
        command = "xdotool type 'chrome://inspect'&&xdotool key Return"
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = t+1
```

Comment: That's a really ugly hack... but it works! Thanks

Comment: @RemcoHaszing always looking for the clean solution. But if there isn't, tools like `xdotool` are great :)

Comment: @RemcoHaszing Hi Remco, found out that occasionally the window appears too late for `xdotool`. The edit always works. If you need more then one `chromium` command, let me know, then the command should be made an argument.